# Sign of Euro currency in textbox

Tags: c#

I have a textbox the inside the user can write amount of money. Is it possible to put a euro currency sign inside the textbox so whatever the user writes then the euro sign be on the left side of the amount?.

Comment: Why don't you just put a `label` with value `€` next to the `textbox`?

Comment: You can make a mask, are you using winforms/xaml/asp.net/etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about windows application than you can use Alt code for that, take a label next to your textbox and in it's text property type 0128 with alt pressed.

[See this](http://www.alt-codes.net/euro_alt_code.php)

It would look something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a `Label` or you could write following `onload` event:

```
txtMoney.Text = "€";
```

Comment: I dont know sign for euro, and that doesnt effects the anser.

Answer (score 0):

I’d do this with a custom background image, create an image of the number sign you want and set it as the background for the TextBox.

```
<TextBox Name="myTextBox" TextChanged="OnTextBoxTextChanged" Width="200">
  <TextBox.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="TextBoxBackground.gif" AlignmentX="Left" Stretch="None" />
  </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```